# Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at D:\ImageMark\opt\siips\classa\patches\alter_db.pl line 421

Tags: perl, informix, dbd

```
if ($insert_ver) {
   $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq|
      insert into db_change (database_version,
       script_name, run_date) values (?,?,?) |);
   $sth->execute("$SQLFILES{$serverType[$serverIndex]}{DBVERSION}[$fileIndex]",
                 "$SQLFILES{$serverType[$serverIndex]}{FILENAME}[$fileIndex]",
                 "$currentDate");
 }
```

I am getting the error shown below when I ran `alter_db.pl` which is the script that updates the Informix database:

> Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at
> D:\ImageMark\opt\siips\classa\patches\alter_db.pl line 421.

Comment: $dbh = databaseConnect("$dbName", $autoCommit, $debug);

Comment: Create the connection with attribute `{ RaiseError => 1 }` or `{ PrintError => 1 }` or both (`{ RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 1 }`).  At least you'll know when things are going wrong.  If you won't use either, the onus is on you to check that methods work correctly — producing defined handles, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You should change your code to:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare(qq|
     insert into db_change (database_version,
         script_name, run_date) values (?,?,?)
     |) || die "Can't prepare statement: $DBI::errstr";
```

Then you would get the appropriate error.

Comment: The above error is thrown only when table has some data in the database. If table doesn't have nay data then It works fine. This is leading to the confusion, why the Alter commands are not working when data is present in tables.

Comment: $sth is undefined. That means the "prepare-statement" failed. The reason is in $DBI::errstr

Comment: Can we alter informix table when it has data in it?

Comment: The above error is thrown only when table has some data in the database. I truncated all the tables which has data then script executed successfully. Why alter table commands failing when data is present in the table.

Comment: Change the one statement as told, rerun the script and show the error. Someone might be able to help than.